# Google Cloud KMS App Engine Encrypt not working

Tags: go, google-cloud-kms

I want to encrypt/decrypt some sensitive data in a Google Cloud project with several AppEngine services. I enabled the Cloud KMS API and, via IAM, added the role "Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter" to the App Engine service account(`{projectId}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`).

Then, I created a ring (`my-ring`) and a key within the ring (`my-key`) accepting the default rotating policy (90days). So I have a key like "projects/{my-project-id}/locations/europe-west3/keyRings/my-ring/cryptoKeys/my-key"

I downloaded the App service account json credentials so I can debug the code locally. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variables points to the downloaded file.

When I try to encrypt a message I get the following error: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid grant: account not found"}

My Go code looks as follows:

```golang
func encrypt(plainText []byte) (string, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := kms.NewKeyManagementClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    req := &kmspb.EncryptRequest{Name: variables.EncryptionKey, Plaintext: plainText}
    result, err := client.Encrypt(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("encryption error %s", err))
        return "", err
    }
    return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(result.Ciphertext), nil

}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There could be many reasons: https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35

Answer (score 1):

Everything was ok except that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` was pointing to an account of another projec. It just was my fault